# Azure Bot framework V4- SSO implementation

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service, azure-cognitive-services

Creating a Azure chatbot V4 framework. But not able to see any proper documentation on SSO implementation so far. Is it possible to have single sign on in version 4 or not? can somebody give pointers please?

Comment: Which SDK are you using? And, what channels are you looking to implement SSO on (i.e. Web Chat, Facebook, MS Teams, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's absolutely possible to have SSO in v4 framework. In the documentation there is a part about implementing authentication here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth

For webchat channel itself there is a fresh (released last month) sample of implementing SSO with Oauth here:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/19.a.single-sign-on-for-enterprise-apps#single-sign-on-demo-for-enterprise-apps-using-oauth